# Is it unnecessary to store a double member of a structure at an address that is a multiple of 8?

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

Suppose that **sizeof(int)** and **sizeof(double)** are 4 and 8 respectively and that there is no preprocessor command such as **#pragma pack** before the following code or compiler options with the same function as **#pragma pack** used in the compiler command line

```
typedef struct
{
    int n;
    double d;
} T;
```

then how much is **sizeof(T)**?

I think that it depends on the width of the data bus between the CPU and RAM. If the width is 32 bits, sizeof(T) is 12. If the width is 64 bits, sizeof(T) is 16. On a computer with a 32-bit data bus, to transfer a 64-bit number from CPU to RAM or vice versa, CPU has to access the data bus twice, reading or writing 32 bits at a time, so there is no point in storing the member **d** of the structure **T** at an address that is a multiple of 8.

Do you agree?

(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Your English is very good.

Answer (score 4):

> then how much is `sizeof(T)`?

You are correct, this is highly dependent on the system, the compiler, and the optimization settings. Generally speaking, the compiler knows best, at least in theory, what alignment to pick for the 8-byte `double` member of the structure. Moreover, compiler's decision could be different when you ask it to optimize for a smaller memory footprint compared to when you ask it to optimize for the fastest speed.

Finally, there may be systems where reading eight bytes from addresses aligned at four-byte boundary but not at eight-byte boundary may carry no penalty at all. Again, your compiler is in the best position to know that fact, and avoid padding your `struct` unnecessarily.

The most important thing to remember about the alignment is that you should not assume a particular layout of your `struct`, even if you are not intended to port your product to a different platform, because a change as simple as adding an optimization flag to the makefile may be sufficient to invalidate your assumptions.

Comment: +1 very nicely put, and just to add some of us still use processors that are only 8 bits wide, C is very common for microprocessors and pics.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that a compiler would generate differently aligned structs with different optimization options. Usually you'd still want that code that is compiled with different optimization can be linked together.